# Springs RestTemplate default connection pool

Tags: spring, connection-pooling, resttemplate

Just wondering if RestTemplate out of the box uses connection pooling or does it simply establish a new connection each time ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I believe `RestTemplate` doesn’t use a connection pool to send requests, it uses a `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` that wraps a standard `JDK`’s `HttpURLConnection` opening and closing the connection.

Indeed you can configure `RestTemplate` to use a pooled implementation such as `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` but most-likely you might also need to configure some settings to prevent requests from timing out.

I have blogged about this issue at [Troubleshooting Spring's RestTemplate Requests Timeout](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/12/27/Troubleshooting-Spring-RestTemplate-Requests-Timeout.html)

Comment: Do I need to create my resttemplate beans as prototype if I use pool?

Comment: @EugeneMakarenko No. How many instances of RestTemplate are you planning to instantiate?

Comment: I need 10 RestTemplates for each service for data transfer and 5 RestTemplates for authentication service. Do I need to inject these beans into my services as singletons or to create using the prototype scope per each request if I am going to use the connection pool from your article? I don't understand how the pool will return used RestTemplate back.

Comment: @EugeneMakarenko, why would you need 10 instances? RestTemplate is thread-safe. You can use the same RestTemplate instance to send requests to multiple services. Just configure it properly so that one slow service won't hijack the whole pool.

Comment: thank you! I was wrong. I have another question. I use two types of RestTemplates. The first is configured for authorization and the second uses for data receiving. Can I use one connection pool for them?

Answer (score 40):

Yes, Spring `RestTemplateBuilder` uses Apache HttpClient for pooling ([usage](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/usages)).
`RestTemplateBuilder` creates `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` and uses `HttpClientBuilder`.

`HttpClientBuilder`, by default, sets pool size per route (host) to 5 and  total pool size to 10 ([source](http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=httpClient/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.java)):

```
s = System.getProperty("http.maxConnections", "5"); 
int max = Integer.parseInt(s); 
poolingmgr.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(max); 
poolingmgr.setMaxTotal(2 * max);
```

To check connection pool logging set logging level as follows:

```
org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager=TRACE
```

Comment: RestTemplateBuilder? This answer may be correct but not seeing RestTemplateBuilder in spring dependencies.   If you do new RestTemplate(), you're getting a SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory not HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.   Using new RestTemplate(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory); seems the way to go.

Comment: This answer is correct. Don't be confused if you find different defaults (e.g. 2/ 20 or 5/25) when browsing the Internet. Those apply if you instantiate `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` directly ([Source](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/6ba9b4acdcba411a035503e3eae9e17b64bcc59b/httpclient5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/io/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java#L110-L111)). And those values also have been changed over the years ...  But as said, Spring Boot uses `HttpClientBuilder` which has its own defaults.

Comment: @Volodymyr Kret did you find any reference in the Spring implementation to the setting of these 2 values? Or has Spring changed the strategy since 2018?

Comment: @DanielPop I was looking for these 2 configs in documentation, but no luck:( You can try to set them as env variables, though it isn't the best practice

Comment: it uses Apache HttpClient for pooling if included in your dependencies and RestTemplateBuilder was used in a correct way! If you have performance issues during establishing http connections I would always debug in detail if everything is working correctly

Comment: Also check ClientHttpRequestFactorySupplier - it's default request factory for rest template builder. Likely you will receive apache http pool with 5 connections only.

Answer (score 19):

By default RestTemplate creates new Httpconnection every time and closes the connection once done.

If you need to have a connection pooling under rest template then you may use different implementation of the ClientHttpRequestFactory that pools the connections.

```
new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory())
```

Comment: Actually, not that simple. Connection pools per each RestTemplate are there: HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory->HttpClients.createSystem()->HttpClientBuilder->PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Answer (score 19):

You can create a Bean for `RestTemplate` and config there :

```
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(100);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig
        .custom()
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000) // timeout to get connection from pool
        .setSocketTimeout(5000) // standard connection timeout
        .setConnectTimeout(5000) // standard connection timeout
        .build();

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                                             .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                                             .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();

    ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);


    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

And there are a lot config you can do. Refer to https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html

**EDIT**

If you want to use micrometer metrics you should also use a [RestTemplateBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56188596/1909531) for constructing the RestTemplate.

Comment: I really like your solution and I'd like to suggest 2 improvements: 1. Use RestTemplateBuilder 2. Also set setConnectTimeout() May I edit your answer or should I better post a separate answer?

Comment: Please update if needed, always welcome suggestions and improvements

Comment: I recommend to set a small ConnectionRequestTimeout (e.g. 100ms). This is the time until the client waits to get a connection from the pool. If it does not get a connection within 100ms an exception is thrown. In some cases this might be a simple replacement to an extra circuit breaker. What do others think?

Answer (score 3):

#### In case of using Spring Boot configured with Apache HttpClient  (having `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient` library in dependencies)

There is a default connection pool configured by PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Default concurrent settings for connections (you can find more about default settings here https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html):

> PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager maintains a maximum limit of connections on a per route basis and in total. Per default this implementation will create no more than 2 concurrent connections per given route and no more 20 connections in total. For many real-world applications these limits may prove too constraining, especially if they use HTTP as a transport protocol for their services.

Answer (score 1):

We can use okhttpclient underneath spring's rest template to use connection pooling. A detailed blog on this below

https://www.bytesville.com/changing-httpclient-in-spring-resttemplate/

Comment: Indeed, OkHttp is a nice alternative implementation. Also the feature set is different. E. g. if you need a Read Timeout, that's not feasible with Apache HttpClient (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6764373/193705), but it is with OkHttp. Apache's Client might have unique features too. In every case it's widely used - so to say "battle tested".