# Custom RestTemplate using requestFactory of RestTemplateBuilder in SpringBoot 2.1.x is not backward compatible with version 1.5.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

In ***Spring Boot 1.5.x***, I was creating a custom `RestTemplate` like below:

```
@Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    poolingConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(restTemplateProps.getMaxConnectionsPerPool());
    poolingConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(restTemplateProps.getMaxDefaultConnectionPerRoute());
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(poolingConnectionManager).build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory =
        new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(restTemplateProps.getConnectionTimeout());
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(restTemplateProps.getSocketTimeout());
    return restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory).build();
  }
```

But, after migrating to ***Spring Boot 2.1.x***, the above code doesn't compile. Looks like `requestFactory` doesn't take `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` as an input parameter.

Can anyone suggest how can I make the above code work in Spring Boot 2.1.x?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After digging deeper into the source code of `RestTemplateBuilder` of ***Spring Boot 2.1.x***, I found that they have removed the method `requestFactory(ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory)`. That means you can no longer inject the `ClientHttpRequestFactory` object into `requestFactory` method.

But, it accept a `Supplier<ClientHttpRequestFactory>` as the input now. So if you have only one restTemplate and one requestFactory, all you need to do is register a `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` bean in Spring context and pass a `ClientHttpRequestFactorySupplier` to `requestFactory` method. The supplier will automatically detect your `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` and return you the required RestTemplate.

Refer the below code for that:

```
@Bean
  public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    poolingConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(restTemplateProps.getMaxConnectionsPerPool());
    poolingConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(restTemplateProps.getMaxDefaultConnectionPerRoute());
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(poolingConnectionManager).build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory =
        new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(restTemplateProps.getConnectionTimeout());
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(restTemplateProps.getSocketTimeout());
    return clientHttpRequestFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  public RestTemplate authRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(new ClientHttpRequestFactorySupplier()).build();
  }
```

For those who are interested in all the changes made to RestTemplateBuilder in SpringBoot 2.1.x, please refer [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/11d4426b4d7455f6eb780dbd566b7dfad2a39ef2#diff-ed45909036d2facdbfa954ab873a7f40).

Comment: Additional (and important) info: the [`ClientHttpRequestFactorySupplier()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.M1/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/ClientHttpRequestFactorySupplier.html) class exists only in Spring Boot *2.1.0* and above; thus, the solution applies to SpringBoot2.1.x+, and not to 2.x.x as stated.

Comment: ok but what if you have 2 restTemplate which need 2 distinct "requestFactory" ? How do you chose which requestFactory get injected into which restTemplate since it's auto detected by "ClientHttpRequestFactorySupplier()" ?

Comment: I think you already got the answer, it can be done by implementing your own Supplier.

Answer (score 12):

Or even easier, just:

```
 restTemplatebuilder.requestFactory(() -> new 
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient)).build();
```

Comment: Or even easier with Kotlin, just:
`restTemplateBuilder
        .requestFactory { HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient)).build() }

Answer (score 7):

Here is a more general solution if you have multiple restTemplates which need different requestFactories (and not an auto-injection of the first one found) :

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder, ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return builder.requestFactory(new MyRequestFactorySupplier()).build();
  }

  class MyRequestFactorySupplier implements Supplier<ClientHttpRequestFactory> {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpRequestFactory get() {

      // Using Apache HTTP client.
      HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
      HttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();
      HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
      requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false); // When sending large amounts of data via POST or PUT, it is recommended to change this property to false, so as not to run out of memory.
      return requestFactory;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I have tried this but I get a InvocationTargetException / NullPointerException

Comment: HttpClientBuilder is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can also just do this:

```
restTemplatebuilder.requestFactory(() -> { return new 
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);});
```